Union of two subsets ( Not a subspace) of a vector space
The question was posed in one of my lectures. It goes as follows

Suppose U and W are any two subsets of a vector space V, such that both U and W are not a subspace of V, then is the union of U and W not a subspace?

The question was intended to find examples such that U and W are not subspaces, but $\,\, U\cup W$  is a subspace.
One such example I could come up with was:
Consider,
V = $\mathbb R^2$
$$ U = \left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
|\,\, a\in \mathbb R \right\} \bigcup 
\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ b
\end{bmatrix}
|\,\, b\in \mathbb R \right\}$$
$$W = \left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\ b
\end{bmatrix}
|\,\, ab \neq 0 \right\}
$$
i.e. $U$ is the union of $X$ and $Y$ axis, whereas $W$ is the rest of the $X-Y$ plane after removing the X and Y axis.
$\therefore U \cup W = \mathbb R^2$ , which is a vector space.
A follow-up discussion on this didn't happen, so I wanted to verify if my example is correct.

Yes, that works.  More simply:  Consider the real line minus the point ${1}$, and the point ${1}$.

@lulu That's even a much simpler example. Thanks!

Similarly $[0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty, 0)$

That is right. There are simpler examples e.g., you can simply remove a point $v\neq0$ from $\Bbb R^n$, call that $U$, and $W=\{v\}$. $W$ is clearly not a subspace, and neither is $U$ since $v/2+v/2=v$.
